# Ajaxtoolkit TextboxWatermarkExtender: How to change the text from Javascript

Tags: asp.net

I think thaAjaxControlToolkitTextBoxWrapperThis use to work, but I think that upgrading to te latest version of teh Toolkit (4 something) broke it:

```
    var txtExpireYear = document.getElementById("ctl00_phPageContent_dtmPassportExpirationDate_txtYear");
  txtExpireYear.AjaxControlToolkitTextBoxWrapper.set_Value(dtmDateOfExpire.getFullYear());
```

I now get the error:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'AjaxControlToolkitTextBoxWrapper' is null or not an object
```

Executing this:

txtExpireYear.innerText="value1"
txtExpireYear.value="value2"

results in the watermark text being changed, not the textbox's text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

Change

```
txtExpireYear.AjaxControlToolkitTextBoxWrapper.set_Value(dtmDateOfExpire.getFullYear());
```

To this:

```
txtExpireYear.TextBoxWrapper.set_Value(dtmDateOfExpire.getFullYear())
```

If it doesn't work, swap the ScriptManager control you are using for the AjaxToolkit replacement control "ToolkitScriptManager"

Answer (score 3):

The text of the textbox is handled by the behavior object of the TextBoxWatermarkExtender.

To access this object in javascript, first specify an ID for the behavior:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="myTextBox" ... />
<ajaxtoolkit:TextBoxWatermarkExtender ID="myTextBoxWatermark" BehaviorID="myTextBoxBehavior" TargetControlID="myTextBox"  WatermarkText="Enter data here ..." ... />
```

In javascript, find this object and use set_Text() method

```
$find('myTextBoxBehavior').set_Text('Entered Data');
```

Similar, there is a get_Text() method, to get the actual value of the textbox

Comment: That looks like the declarative equivalent to what I said used to work in the previous version of the tool kit.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the text of the watermark itself, there is also a `set_WatermarkText()` method.

Expanding on Edwin's example:

```
$find('myTextBoxBehavior').set_WatermarkText('Entered Data');
```